# Bokeh: Column DataSource part giving error

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to create an interactive bokeh plot that holds multiple data and I am not sure why I am getting the error

ValueError: expected an element of ColumnData(String, Seq(Any)),got {'x': 6.794, 'y': 46.8339999999999, 'country': 'Congo, Dem. Rep.', 'pop': 3.5083789999999997, 'region': 'Sub-Saharan Africa'}

```
source = ColumnDataSource(data={
'x'       : data.loc[1970].fertility,
'y'       : data.loc[1970].life,
'pop'     : (data.loc[1970].population / 20000000) + 2,
'region'  : data.loc[1970].region,
```

})

I have tried two different data sets by importing data from excel and have been running out of issues on exactly why this happening.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As the name suggests, the `ColumnDataSource` is a data structure for storing columns of data. This means that the value of every key in `.data` must be a column, i.e. a Python list, a NumPy array, or a Pandas series. But you are trying to assign plain numbers as the values, which is what the error message is telling you:

I am trying to create an interactive bokeh plot that holds multiple data and I am not sure why I am getting the error

> expected an element of ColumnData(String, Seq(Any))

This is saying acceptable, expected values are dicts that map strings to sequences. But what you passed is clearly not that:

> got {'x': 6.794, 'y': 46.8339999999999, 'country': 'Congo, Dem. Rep.', 'pop': 3.5083789999999997, 'region': 'Sub-Saharan Africa'}

The value for `x` for instance is just the number 6.794 and not an array or list, etc.

Comment: As a matter of fact. Every data is a part of column. This excel file in from Kaggle (gapminder)

Comment: Can someone please help here?

Comment: It's literally not  of a column, at least not how you are supplying it. That's what the error states, unambiguously.

Comment: In particular, is you only have data for Afghanistan as shown above, then pulling out loc 1970 pulls out only a single scalar value (not an array)

Comment: If you don't believe me, you can just print out the value that you are passing to `data` and see for yourself.

Comment: I believe you but can you please give me a solution?

Comment: Make the things you are passing into lists. i.e. put the current scalar values inside brackets `[...]` so that they become 1-element Python lists instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this:

```
source = ColumnDataSource({str(c): v.values for c, v in df.items()})
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a solution.  I think the problem is in getting the data from df.

```
source = ColumnDataSource(data={
    'x'       : data[data['Year'] == 1970]['fertility'],
    'y'       : data[data['Year'] == 1970]['life'],
    'pop'     : (data[data['Year'] == 1970]['population']/20000000) + 2,
    'region'  : data[data['Year'] == 1970]['region']
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem using this same dataset.
My solution was to import the csv in pandas using "Year" as index column.

```
data = pd.read_csv(csv_path,  index_col='Year')
```